# dictionary changed size during iteration in multithreading app

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary

I do not know how to solve this problem:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/cabinet_dev/cabinet/lib/python3.4/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py",
>   line 458, in fire_timers
>       timer()   File "/usr/local/cabinet_dev/cabinet/lib/python3.4/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/timer.py",
>   line 58, in **call**
>       cb(*args, **kw)   File "/usr/local/cabinet_dev/cabinet/lib/python3.4/site-packages/eventlet/greenthread.py",
>   line 218, in main
>       result = function(*args, **kwargs)   File "./monitor.py", line 148, in caughtBridge
>       for call in self.active.keys(): RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

In the code below:

```
def caughtBridge(self):
    while True:
        event = self.bridgeQueue.get()
        uniqueid1 = str(event.headers.get('Uniqueid1'))
        uniqueid2 = str(event.headers.get('Uniqueid2'))
        for call in self.active.keys():
            if self.active[call]['uniqueid'] == uniqueid1:
                self.active[call]['uniqueid2'] = uniqueid2
            if self.active[call]['uniqueid'] == uniqueid1:
                for listener in self.listeners:
                    for number in listener.getNumbers():
                        if number == self.active[call]['exten']:
                            if not self.active[call]['answered']:
                                self.sendEvent({"status": "bridge", "id": self.active[call]['uniqueid'],
                                                "number": self.active[call]['exten']},
                                               listener.getRoom())
                                self.__callInfo(self.active[call], listener.getRoom())
                                self.active[call]['answered'] = True
        self.bridgeQueue.task_done()
```

Comment: what does `self.active` look like? more specifically `self.active.keys()`, as that is causing the error:  `line 148, in caughtBridge for call in self.active.keys(): RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`.


you have something changing the dictionary while this code is running.

Comment: Yes, in the process of working with this array it works in several threads and it is obvious that it causes an error) The object has approximately the following form:
active = {}
        active['uniqueid'] = str(event.headers.get('Uniqueid'))
        active['exten'] = str(event.headers.get('Exten'))
        active['context'] = str(event.headers.get('Context'))
        active['channel'] = str(event.headers.get('Channel'))
   ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a copy of `self.active.keys()`, for example:

```
for call in list(self.active.keys()):
```

Didn't see if you **add** or **remove** `dict` Entries?
In case of **adding**, the other Threads will not see the added `dict` Entries.
In case of **removing**, the current Thread will fail with ***Key Error***,
you have to catch these.

For example:

```
for call in list(self.active.keys()):
    <Lock that call to prevent removing>
    if call in self.active:
        ...
                      self.active[call]['answered'] = True
    else:
        # call removed do nothing
    <Unlocked that call to do whatever in other Thread>
self.bridgeQueue.task_done()
```

Read about  Python » 3.6.2 Documentation: [threading.html#lock-objects](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#lock-objects)

Basicly implement Pair Methods `self.lock(call)` and `self.unlock(call)`, for instance:

> **Untested Code**:
>   To prevent **Deadlocks** you have to guarantee `self.unlock(call)` will be reached!
>
> ```
> class xxx
>     def __init__....
>         self_lock = threading.Lock
>         # Init all  self.active[call]['lock'] = False
>
> def lock(self, call):
>     # self._lock ist class threading.Lock
>     # self._lock has to be the same for all Threads
>     with self._lock:
>         if call in self.active and not self.active[call]['lock']:
>             self.active[call]['lock'] = True
>             return True
>         else:
>             return False
>
> def unlock(self, call):
>     with self._lock:
>         self.active[call]['lock'] = False
>
> # Usage:
> for call in list(self.active.keys()):
>     if self.lock(call):
>         ...
>                       self.active[call]['answered'] = True
>
>         self.unlock(call)
>     else:
>         # call removed do nothing
> self.bridgeQueue.task_done()
> ```

Comment: How can I catch them? Yes, there is a procedure for adding and removing, they are all started in eventlet.spawn ()

Comment: How can I use a lock in the module eventlet?